# How can I compute the following expression

Tags: r

I want to solve `$$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{x=1}^{100}x^y\,dy$$` in R. I use the following codes.

```
x=c(1:100)
f=function(y) sum(x^y)
integrate(f,0,1)
```

But I got this error message:

> Error in integrate(f, 0, 1) : 
>     evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In x^y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

How can solve this problem without use of "for".

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not vectorized in `y` and `integrate` needs a vectorized function.

```
x=c(1:100)

f= Vectorize(function(y) sum(x^y), "y")

integrate(f,0,1)
#1226.54 with absolute error < 1.4e-11
```